# Why can one write to array passed of allocated memory from malloc?

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int n = 8;
  int *ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  for (int i = 0; i < 33624; i++)
  {
    ar[i] = i;
    // printf("%d\n", ar[i]);
  }

  // ar = realloc(ar, sizeof(int) * 10);
}
```

Allows me to write to `33623*4` (sizeof int) bytes pass the allocated memory. Trying to access `33624` results in segfault. Why can I do so and why is the limit specifically `33623` for `8*4` byte allocations?

Next, using the realloc even after the "writing pass the allowed boundary", which previously did not result in segfault (if was less then 33624), now resluts in

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

No matter what size argument I supply (you can see in comment that new size is just 10 ints). So how the realloc knows about the writes pass the boundary?

I am asking becuase If as programmer I asked for say 100 bytes from `malloc`, but it gives me much more - as argument for this is the above "posibility to write pass the allowed boundary", I don't have reason to `realloc`, becuase the allocated size is bigger then requested.

So If I could just derive the true size the malloc gives me from the requested size (again, what is the relation between (`8*4`, which was requested, and `4*33623`, which is the last memory location access allowed before segfault), I can calculate with this size and not using `realloc` at all

Comment: C has no bounds-checking at all. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*. It's up to you as the programmer to make sure your program doesn't go out of bounds of allocated memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't care about UB.  Unless I got segfault, the program goes on.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour ranges from immediate crash (generaly segfault) to expected behaviour. Errors or weird behaviour in unrelated part of the programs are also possible. This is why it is seen as hell by C programmers...

Comment: You need to understand that a segfault is best case scenario for UB. The hidden damage is the bad stuff.

Comment: @Gerhardh what "hiddent" demage? I don't see any "hidden demage". Eveything works, so you analog with burning house is nonsense

Comment: But when you go out of bounds the program ***isn't*** behaving "correctly". You don't know what data might be overwritten. And UB *will* come and bite you in your behind when you least expect it. And if you submit code containing UB at your work and claim that "it goes correctly" then you will not last very long.

Comment: Your argument is similar to saying "I saw a black bird today. Therefore all birds must be black." A sample-size of one doesn't make good statistics.

Answer (score 0):

**Accessing invalid memory is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).**

Trying to access the memory location, which is not allocated to the program, is invalid memory access. In your case, index value > 7 (as C uses 0-based indexing) will cause UB.

Comment: Yes, but the specific question is why do some writes work but one particular write does not work.   This will of course be system and implementation dependent.

Comment: @mmixLinus because the nature of **undefined** is that you cannot expect any specific defined behaviour

Comment: @mmixLinus ...but nothing is guaranteed by the standard,

Comment: @mmixLinus Also, implementation-defined behaviour and undefined behaviour are two separate analogies.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the UB is not visible unless segfaul, coredump, abort, or other error. Until then, it is just theory

Comment: @milanHrabos That's what makes it more deadly, and gives so many more reasons to consider my earlier statement seriously.

Comment: @Gerhardh  I think you are both missing the point of the question.  The OP seeks to understand what may be causing the behaviour they are seeing.

Comment: @milanHrabos "the UB is not visible unless" That means, if you close your eyes, the house is not burning because it is not visible to you?

Comment: @Gerhardh comparing memory errors with burning house is really ridiculous

Comment: @milanHrabos The analogy applies. Just because you don't see that a bad thing is happening doesn't mean that it's not a bad thing. A more mild analogy would be eating slightly rotten food. Just because you don't get sick all the time doesn't mean that you should keep eating it. Also, segfaults, etc. aren't the only impacts of undefined behaviour. You could, for example, overwrite other objects, leading to seemingly unrelated bugs later, in other bits of code.

Comment: But perhaps a better analogy would be with faulty wiring.  It would be ridiculous not to care about faulty wiring in your house unless it started a fire.  Bad wiring carries a high *risk* of starting that fire at an unpredictable point in the future, it reduces the home's value, it may create issues for home maintenance and renovations, and you cannot be confident that it is not causing damage that you do not recognize.  That's actually a *very* good analogy for code whose behavior is or can be undefined.